# How to convert unicode to html tag?

Tags: javascript, xss

I have the following Unicode

```
%u201c%u003e%u003c%u0073%u0063%u0072%u0069%u0070%u0074%u003e%u0061%u006c%u0065%u007
2%u0074%u0028%u0027%u0078%u0073%u0073%u0027%u0029%u003c%u002f%u0073%u0063%u0072%u00
69%u0070%u0074%u003e%u003c%u0021%u002d%u002d
```

Is there any JavaScript code to convert the above Unicode to the html code?

This is regarding the XSS attack issue.

Comment: how are you encoding this? 'decodeURIComponent' is one way of decoding unicode, but it doesn't agree with your encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `unescape` function:

```
var string = '%u201c%u003e%u003c%u0073%u0063%u0072%u0069%u0070%u0074%u003e%u0061%u006c%u0065%u0072%u0074%u0028%u0027%u0078%u0073%u0073%u0027%u0029%u003c%u002f%u0073%u0063%u0072%u0069%u0070%u0074%u003e%u003c%u0021%u002d%u002d';
alert(unescape(string));
```